# How do I convert data using powershell and then grab the users I want

Tags: excel, powershell, pscustomobject

How do I create a variable to store  data for further manipulation and then Convert the data coming out of the Excel document into a PSCustomObject and then filter it down to the people I care about

Here's what I have so far:

```
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
$path = "C:\Users\Test.xlsx"
$excel.workbooks.open($path)
$excel.Visible = $True

$variable = $excel.workbooks.open($path)
$worksheet = $variable.activeSheet


For ($j = 6; $j -lt 124; $j++) {
    For ($i = 1; $i -lt 11; $i++) {
     $worksheet.Cells.Item($j,$i).text
    }   
}
```

Comment: [Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/) depending on the excel file using a csv could a way, too

Comment: @OlafReitz Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't require adding additional properties to your PSCustomObject during its creation, the first part of your question may be answered by using [PSExcel module](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) from RamblingCookieMonster. Checkout the example **Export and import data** and the Import-XLSX module.

Once the .XLSX has been imported to a variable, you can pipe it to ForEach-Object to retrieve only the people you care about. In the example below, I have a column in my .XLSX called 'Name' which is used with the Where-Object cmdlet.

```
Import-Module \\pathToModule\PSExcel

$FileContents = Import-XLSX -path "myFile.xlsx"

$FileContents | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Where-Object Name -EQ 'User I care about'
}
```